# Symfony vichimage upload make two labels in formbuilder

Tags: symfony, twig, vichuploaderbundle

Hi guys fro some reason the form builder make me two labels when i specified my own label.

Here is the config for the vich image bundle:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/products
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/products
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
        apartment_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/apartment
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/apartment
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
        slide_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/slider
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/slider
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
        point_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/point
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/point
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
        object_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/object
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/object
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
        gallery_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/gallery
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/gallery
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

Here is the buildForm:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations',array(
            'required_locales' => array('bg','en')
        ))
        ->add('canvas')
        ->add('mode','checkbox', array('label'=> 'In sell','required'=>false))
        ->add('lat','text',array('label'=>'Latitude'))
        ->add('longt','text',array('label'=>'Longitude '))
        ->add('imageLeadFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'label'=>'Lead image Home Page (720x534)',
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))
        ->add('imageLocationFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))
        ->add('imagePinFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))
        ->add('imageAligmentFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))
        ->add('imageAligmentIconFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))
        ->add('imageArchitectureIconFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))->add('imageStageIconFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))->add('imageLocationIconFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))->add('imageGalleryIconFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))->add('imageColumFirstFile', 'vich_image', array(
        'required' => false,
        'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))->add('imageColumSecondFile', 'vich_image', array(
        'required' => false,
        'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
    ))->add('imageColumThirdFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
    ))->add('imageColumForthFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))
    ;
}
```

So when i try to make different label like this (i want to include the dimensions of the image the admin to know what image need to be provided):

```
        ->add('imageLeadFile', 'vich_image', array(
            'label'=>'Lead image Home Page (720x534)',
            'required' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ))
```

I got second label on top...

[image]

I have seen the uploader template and there has no label:

```
{% block vich_file_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="vich-file">
        {{ form_row(form.file) }}
        {% if form.delete is defined %}
        {{ form_row(form.delete) }}
        {% endif %}

        {% if download_uri is defined and download_uri %}
        <a href="{{ download_uri }}">{{ 'download'|trans({}, 'VichUploaderBundle') }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

{% block vich_image_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="vich-image">
        {{ form_row(form.file) }}
        {% if form.delete is defined %}
        {{ form_row(form.delete) }}
        {% endif %}

        {% if download_uri is defined and download_uri %}
         <a href="{{ download_uri }}"><img src="{{ download_uri }}" alt="" /></a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if show_download_link and download_uri is defined and download_uri%}
        <a href="{{ download_uri }}">{{ 'download'|trans({}, 'VichUploaderBundle') }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

The config to use the external twig files in the CoreBundle:

```
form_themes:
    # other form themes
    - 'CoreBundle:VichForm:fields.html.twig'
```

What could possibly make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old question but it hasn't been answered properly, so, for future reference:

In VichUploaderBundle template file 'fields.html.twig', do this:

```
<div class="vich-file">
    {{ form_widget(form.file) }}
    {% if form.delete is defined %}
    {{ form_row(form.delete, {'label': 'Delete'}) }}
    {% endif %}
```

And the same thing below for the image widget.

```
<div class="vich-image">
    {{ form_widget(form.file) }}
    {% if form.delete is defined %}
    {{ form_row(form.delete, {'label': 'Delete'}) }}
    {% endif %}
```

(This is just basic [Twig](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-view-variables) BTW)

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem, apparently without explanation. When rereading and rereading the [documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/form/vich_file_type.md), I realised I forgot this configuration below. It solved my problem:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        # other form themes
        - 'VichUploaderBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Comment: Hum it is not the case i have added the config for the templates and it is in the CoreBundle. Those twig examples  {% block vich_file_widget %} and  {% block vich_image_widget %} are in the CoreBundle I can remove the  {{ form_row(form.file) }} but i don't know from where it appear also....

Answer (score 1):

In the uploader template do this

```
{% block vich_file_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="vich-file">
        {{ form_widget(form.file) }} {# here is the change #}
```

or other says that in twig you can set the label to false `'label'=>false`

Comment: I have try everything the only work around was to remove the label twig element.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `vich_image` to `file`, like this:

```
->add('imageLeadFile', 'file', array(
    'label'=>'Lead image Home Page (720x534)',
    'required' => false,
    'allow_delete' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
    'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
))
```